# Catch-all Domains Windows DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, wildcard

We are trying to set up Windows DNS for our nameservers ns1.sitegen.co and ns2.sitegen.co.

Is is possible to catchall domain names using those nameservers in Windows DNS instead of creating individual forward lookup zones for every domain we wish to host in IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

If you're DNS servers are not authoritative name servers for the domains you host web sites for, you don't need to worry about DNS.

All you need to do, is configure an A record (aka. Host record) for `www.domain.com` and point it to the public IP of the web server.

---

I'm not sure I understand your question. If you are setting up DNS servers for internal use (answering lookups from local machines with internet access), this is what you need

1. Create [forwarders on each DNS Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773370%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).
2. Check "Disable Recursion" if you want all queries forwarded (instead of root hint lookups).

Now, all queries for domains for which you do **NOT** have a forward lookup zone *OR* a conditional forwarder, will be forwarded to the "default" servers configured in step 1

Comment: Thanks for your response. We are using the server to host Internet sites in IIS. For example, if "domain.com" uses our name servers (above) and so does "domain2.com" - can we catch them both with a single forward lookup zone and point any requests to our localhost. We have tried disabling recursion but this also disables our forwarder so the server cannot resolve any domain names locally. Hope that makes sense - we're pretty new to this. Thanks again.

Comment: I think you're a bit confused about the role of DNS vs. the web server.

Comment: Probably. If we add a forward lookup zone for "domain.com" and configure it to point to localhost and the domain uses our nameservers - we can visit that domain in a browser and be directed to our webserver - that works great. However, we want to avoid adding lookup zones for every domain by using a wildcard - if possible?

Comment: That is what we usually do for sites however we will also be hosting mail, ftp etc and to keep it simple for customers with their own domains (we just wanted to provide them with two nameservers instead of just creating individual records)

Comment: If you just want it to answer for `domain.com` and not `www.domain.com`, you could configure a zone for `.com` and add a wildcard record... But please don't to that - it would be considered malpractice, since you don't have authority over `.com`